# Need help with firewall - Accept FTP connections from outside

Tags: centos, iptables, ftp

I am hoping you can help out. Our DevOps guy is out of the office at our agency and our partners need access to our FTP. We have it locked down to our office but need to open it so that people outside our office can connect for a few weeks while development from our partners complete work.

Unfortunately, I have limited knowledge of the server-side stuff and am still learning.

We are running centos 7 and iptables.. here are the rules we have currently:

```
 sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
60692   98M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  138  8258 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                        
 1943 90860 INPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                     
 1943 90860 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             any                                                                                                    where
 1943 90860 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                      
  465 18696 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                        
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywher                                                                                                    e
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere                                                                                                                 anywhere
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywh                                                                                                    ere
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere                                                                                                                 anywhere
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anyw                                                                                                    here
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 60733 packets, 193M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
60757  193M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                    

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  any    +       anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhe                                                                                                    re
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywh                                                                                                    ere
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anyw                                                                                                    here
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                        

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhe                                                                                                    re
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywh                                                                                                    ere
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anyw                                                                                                    here

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
 1943 90860 IN_public  all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
 1943 90860 IN_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                    
 1943 90860 IN_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywher                                                                                                    e
 1943 90860 IN_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhe                                                                                                    re
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                        

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
  498 22176 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
  979 49936 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:ftp ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:webcache ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpts:ndmps:50000 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:ftp ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:ftp-data ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                     
   24  1224 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                 tcp dpt:smtp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CentOS system is using Firewalld, so you'd want to update the firewall configuration using it.  You'd use the `firewall-cmd` command to [modify the rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-working_with_zones).  For example, to allow the FTP service on the public zone, you'd use:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-service=ftp --zone=public
```

You can see that there are rules already defined with firewalld in the output of your `iptables` command, which is why you see all those tables with '_public' in their name.